# Given the mean of three numbers and the value of one of the numbers, is it possible to determine the values of the other two numbers?

Tags: average

Given the mean (average) of three numbers *and* the value of one of the three numbers, is it possible to determine the values of the other two numbers?

For example, given the average of numbers *x*, *y*, and 21 is 23, is it possible to find the values of *x* and *y*? And could this be applied to where, if you the average of a group of numbers and the values of all but two of the numbers, could you determine the remaining values? (Example: if the average of *n* numbers is *a*, knowing *n*-2 of the values and knowing *a*, can you determine the other two values?)

Comment: Explicit counter example: $a,b,c$, with $b = 2 = ~$ mean value.  $(a,c)$ could be (for example) $(1,3)$ or $(0,4)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the information you have given:${x+y+21\over 3}=23$
, thus $x+y=48$

but there are infinitely many solutions to this equation so no unique solutions.
In the general case you have given, you end up with the sum of the 2 numbers being some value so you also end up with infinitely many solutions.